# Handshake GCDAsyncSocket

Tags: ssl, encryption, asyncsocket, handshake, gcdasyncsocket

I use in my iPhone app the GCDAsyncSocket class to communicate with a Java server. It works well without SSL. Does anybody knows how to activate SSL with self signed certificates? I can't find how I can import my certificate in the code.

Please help, lost there several days ago and can't find a way out.

Comment: if it's still not solved, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407397/objective-c-eveluate-server-certificate-signed-by-our-own-pki-root-ca-on-tls . maybe it helps